# Check for disabled button fails with selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

I have a simple assertion on a disabled button within my selenium test that fails. The method expects the button to be disabled but when I run the test it fails stating that the button is actually enabled.

I use Ruby/Rspec and this is the code used to check that button is disabled. I've removed the references to the class and page object but the button object locator used is by :id.

`expect(Page.btn.enabled?).to be false`

Here is the html of the page for the disabled button I am testing:

`<input type="submit" name="ctl00$bodyContentPlaceHolder$btnContinueToAddress" value="Next" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$bodyContentPlaceHolder$btnContinueToAddress&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_bodyContentPlaceHolder_btnContinueToAddress" class="btn btn-primary btn-block disabledContent">`

I would expect the selenium test to pass as the button IS disabled on the page, but the rspec results show:

expected false
     got true

Is the locator used incorrect and the :id is actually enabled? Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in C# you could do a workaround with `element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("disabled")`, try using this logic on Ruby

Comment: I would suggest you use something like byebug, add a `byebug` call right before that line and double check manually if `Page.btn` is the button you think it is and check its status.

Comment: @arieljuod I'm not familiar with `byebug` but I will try that. I can confirm that page.btn is the button I think it is because completing an action on the page enables this button and it is clicked later in the test to transition to the next page. I just want the test to confirm that the button is disabled upon page load until the next action is completed.

Comment: You can also use `save_and_open_page` to inspect the HTML and `save_and_open_screenshot` to view an image of the page. Maybe the button is obscured by something else and the driver can't find it. Finally, I would check something like `expect(page.btn).to be_disabled`.